# Парсинг элементов между тегами br

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
    <br>
    10:11
<span class="chat_text">[Сирень] Ледилика не пришла, в итоге</span>
    <br>
    10:12
[ОМОНОВЕЦ] Создатель партии — <b>Боня</b>.<br>10:12 [ОМОНОВЕЦ] Комментарий к заявке: СВ Девушки 1 этап 3 партия
    <br>
    10:12
[ОМОНОВЕЦ] Минуточку, распределяем роли.<br>10:13 <span class="chat_text">[apaapaapa] всем пока рибята</span>
    <br>
    10:14
[ОМОНОВЕЦ] Игра началась! В игре участвуют: <b>Kaktusson</b>, <b>Problema</b>, <b>Сирень</b>, <b>Melody</b>, <b>Despina</b>, <b>Mercury</b>, <b>Лиззи Борден</b>, <b>bikeladykoenig</b>, <b>Purpur</b>, <b>apaapaapa</b>, <b>Каприз</b>, <b>Kolchuginka</b>, <b>Ambriel</b>, <b>Сакура</b>
    <br>
    10:15
[ОМОНОВЕЦ] Дадим мафии время договориться. Приват включен!
    <br>
    10:15
<span class="chat_text">[Каприз] Всем привет, я чиж</span>
    <br>
    10:17
<span class="chat_text">[Сирень] Сиреневая</span>
    <br>
    10:18
<span class="chat_text">[Problema] Всем мяу, сегодня без фразочки входной</span>
    <br>
    <span class="label label-success">Ход № 2.</span>
    Ход № 2.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    ...
```

Есть такая структура HTML документа (пример можно глянуть [тут](https://www.mafiaonline.ru/log/4181907?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=0cbafdaeaa1e1a42a5ab90ec0ff9843050c46dd0-1604013503-0-AafuJfjf601wvlnyxpU5G3FrpYzpmiQJJ3EhzSChqUXqEtBQ32-cQs29qKW9pnxwBFsHZ-pDRPACBQ5QCZ0GkAh9z0QDwd4QSj_92N-doP_lQ8wIJ6akmPaaPsLg-Ps70Q_eej8Zh0-E1LhpnXzKXyWiBMbn_4ScPICCACaAOs5Zhc1_xp562emCxWDS0S447sU22JFKd3B2_JGQCEUQWY36OW6IqiFYV8qUri3JZ1x1EV96mr-M1v5lOjy_j3BZkrTuEgLybPxie4Prra8eOiM7l1yseskSi3TDn41pawdg)).
Каким образом лучше всего вытащить данные находящиеся между тегами `br`?
В идеале должно быть как-то так:

```
[(mm:ss, text), ('', 'Ход 2'), ...]
```

Важно чтобы именно в такой последовательности, т.е. вытащить сначала то что между `br`, а потом отдельно запарсить `label-succes` не подойдет.

Comment: Предположим, что лог вашего чата находится как текст в переменной. Тогда код `re.split("<br/?>", chat_log_as_string)` нарежет лог в массив строк как раз по тегам `br`. Дальше берёте каждый элемент и парсите.

Comment: Хм, а никаких проблем не будет? Подумаю... Спасибо.

Comment: Разумеется, проблемы будут, только не с тегами `<br>`. В примере используется только тег `<br>`, но для общности можно взять регулярное выражение `</?br/?>` -- мало ли какие есть оригиналы.